# Error: redeclaration differs in ‘constexpr’

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, constexpr, clang++

Clang accepts this code, but GCC rejects it:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  static constexpr double kVal = 0.25f;
};

const double Foo::kVal;
```

(Using clang 3.0 and g++ 4.6.3)

```
~$ clang++ foo.cc -std=c++11 -c 
[ok]
~$ g++ foo.cc -std=c++0x -c 
foo.cc:6:19: error: redeclaration ‘Foo::kVal’ differs in ‘constexpr’
foo.cc:3:34: error: from previous declaration ‘Foo::kVal’
foo.cc:6:19: error: declaration of ‘constexpr const double Foo::kVal’ outside of class is not definition [-fpermissive]
```

Which interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

clang is correct.  It looks like somebody on the gcc team misread or misimplemented:

7.1.5/1:

> If any declaration of a function or function template has `constexpr` specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the `constexpr` specifier.

`Foo::kVal` is obviously not a function or function template.  I don't see anything else in the Standard requiring use of `constexpr` to be consistent from one declaration to the next.

Comment: For a function declaration, both clang and gcc give an error.

Comment: @JoshLee: That's because it is mandatory for a function, but the rule does not apply for variables. Although, I personally would prefer consistency between them.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to declare twice.

```
class Foo {
  public:
   static constexpr double kVal = 0.25f;
};
```

Is all that is needed.

Comment: You do need to if `kVal` is used as an lvalue.